# Movie where suddenly nobody knows the protagonist

Tags: story-identification, movie

It's a bit old, not a TV Series, my guess in about 80/90s era. In the film suddenly nobody knows the protagonist, there's a conspiracy involved, and at the end of the movie, he blew up all the bad guys in a meeting room, he also died in the process.

A memorable scene that I remember is when the bomb nearly detonate, suddenly the bomb is deactivated, after all the bad guys have a small moment of relief, the bomb exploded.

Comment: are you looking for The Unknown? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknown_(2011_film)

Comment: That one's a bit more recent, but it does match a number of details.

Comment: Unfortunately not the unknown, although it does match a lot of my details.